# Formatting XML for Display on an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a table in sqlserver, in that table i have a column having xml file. i am displaying that table in gridview. when we click on button i want to display that particular xml file column in a xml format or export to xml file format.

Comment: Maybe you want to write an HttpHandler to generate the xml file and return it to the user, so that he can download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve like

```
dtbl.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/yourSample.xml"));
```

OR it can be

```
String xml = dtbl.Rows[0]["XMLColumnName"].ToString();
string filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/yourSample.xml");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
xmlWriter.WriteRaw(xml);
xmlWriter.Flush();
xmlWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original XML "cached" (or re-retrieve it, if that is better for your application). Then you simply output to a new window a URL that can retrieve the XML (from cache or database) and show as XML to user. You need to change the response type to XML to achieve this. If this does not make sense, you need to learn a bit about the response header and possibly MIME types.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTPHandler would work to generate the xml file and return to the user, as would writing the XML to the response with the correct content type headers e.g.:

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", dataLength.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        if (dataLength > -1)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Accept-Header", dataLength.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("Attachment;Filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
```

Then write the XML content to the Response in chunks.