# xml format in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a table in sqlserver, in that table i have a column having xml file. i am displaying that table in gridview. when we click on button i want to display that particular xml column file column in a xml format. tank you.
i take one dtalist and writ code like this.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlstOne" runat ="server" >
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat ="server" Text ='<%# XPath("/EXTPOSTTRANSACTION/STLTRANSACTIONINFO/TRANSACTIONTYPE")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat ="server" Text ='<%# XPath("/EXTPOSTTRANSACTION/STLTRANSACTIONINFO/USERID")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

it is giving error

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: XPath DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' must implement IXPathNavigable.
```

please can u help me

```
string sqry = "select NewLoanRequestXML from tbl_newloanxml where newloanid=" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();

da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqry, con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);       

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dtlstOne.DataSource = ds;
    dtlstOne.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting XML for Display on an ASP.NET Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866027/formatting-xml-for-display-on-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: don't post duplicate questions.